# Letting wine reduce before braising

Tags: braising

I've seen recipes for braising (sorry no sources available) that instruct you to deglaze with wine then let it reduce by about half. After the wine has reduced, the next steps are to add in stock, more wine and aromatics, let it come to a simmer on the stove then pop it in the oven to braise.

I'm curious why let the wine you deglaze with reduce if you are going to be adding more wine in before putting it in the oven? This makes no sense to me.

Comment: It is just to add more flavor complexity ?

Comment: I suspect Max is right -- there are plenty of recipes where you might add an ingredient in more than once ... especially ones that are greatly affected by cooking.

Comment: If two of you think that's the answer, maybe post it as one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a question of flavor layers.

Reducing the wine after deglazing will create some deeper flavoring.

It will remove some of the wine's acidity and concentrate the flavor that will complement the stock and wine that will be added later on in the recipe.

Answer (score 0):

When you deglaze with wine three things basically happen. You flash off most of the alcohol, recover the material in the pan, and most importantly concentrate the flavors by reducing the volume in half. If you add the wine and stock, eliminating this step, you can not get the intensity of flavor produced by the deglazing process. Generally, if you have to increase the liquid volume during the brazing process, adding additional stock can be balanced by adding an additional splash of wine to taste.

bulldogbarry